# Passing none to a property causes crashes

Tags: python, properties, nonetype

I'm using properties in order to get/set variables in my class, but when the variable is set to None, the program crashes the next time the variable is set - like in the following code:

```
class Abc(object):
    def __init__(self, a=None):
        self.a = a

    def set_a(self, value):
        self._a = value*5

    def get_a(self):
        return self._a

    a = property(get_a, set_a)

A = Abc()
A.a = 4
print A.a
```

When I run this I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 13, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 3, in __init__
  File "<string>", line 6, in set_a
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

What's the correct way of writing the code to stop this error occurring?

Comment: But if you want to have optional variables being passed in to the function..

Comment: what is value ? in set_a()

Comment: Always include the traceback when you see an error in Python; I've added this one for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `self._a`, not `self.a`; the latter uses the property setter:

```
class Abc(object):
    def __init__(self, a=None):
        self._a = a
```

or use a numeric default instead:

```
class Abc(object):
    def __init__(self, a=0):
        self.a = a
```